# SMT-LIB Benchmarks

Tags: z3, smt, bitvector

I would like to benchmark some SMT solvers and the SMT-LIB Benchmark repository [1,2] seems to be a good place to start.

However, the link has been down for at least some days. Does anyone know any other place where I can find these benchmarks?

[1] http://www.smtlib.org/

[2] http://smtexec.org/exec/smtlib-portal-benchmarks.php

**EDIT:**

The benchmarks are now here:

[1] http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/benchmarks.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server that hosts the SMTLIB benchmarks has broken down and is currently being repaired. According to information I got from Cesare Tinelli, it should be back online some time this week.

Answer (score 1):

The server is now at: http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/ and the benchmarks are now at: **http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/benchmarks.shtml**. I edited the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: The link has changed at some point during the last 5 years. Both http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/ (= http://www.smtlib.org/) and https://www.starexec.org/ are operational at the moment.